# Make API request with cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to connect to an API, which should be done with cURL.

This is what the documentation is telling me to send (with my own data though, this is just and example).

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.reepay.com/v1/subscription \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  -u 'priv_11111111111111111111111111111111:' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"plan":"plan-AAAAA",
           "handle": "subscription-101",
           "create_customer": {
              "handle": "customer-007",
              "email": "joe@example.com"
           },
           "signup_method":"link"}'
```

What I have tried is this, but I get and error:

```
$postdata = array();
    $postdata['plan'] = 'plan-AAAAA';
    $postdata['handle'] = 'subscription-101';
    $postdata['create_customer'] = ["handle" => "customer-007", "email" => "joe@example.com"];
    $postdata['signup_method'] = 'link';
    $cc =  curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.reepay.com/v1/subscription");
    curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $result = curl_exec($cc);
    echo $result;
```

This is the error I get:
*{"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/v1/subscription","timestamp":"2022-10-22T11:42:11.733+00:00","http_status":415,"http_reason":"Unsupported Media Type"}*

Can anyone help me make the correct request?

Comment: The example says, that `application/json` is accepted, but you are posting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You'll need to json_encode the postdata and put it into the body + set the appropriate content-type

Comment: I'll post it as answer if you don't mind, so you can accept it ;)

Comment: @HonkderHase Of course :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example says, that application/json is accepted, but you are posting application/x-www-form-urlencoded. You'll need to json_encode the postdata and put it into the body + set the appropriate content-type.

To be nice, also set 'Content-Length'...

```
$json_data = json_encode($postdata);
curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($json_data)
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you get, I guess you need to set the content-type header as JSON.

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.reepay.com/v1/subscription',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "plan": "plan-AAAAA",
    "handle": "subscription-101",
    "create_customer": {
        "handle": "customer-007",
        "email": "joe@example.com"
    },
    "signup_method": "link"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.reepay.com/v1/subscription');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'priv_11111111111111111111111111111111:');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"plan":"plan-AAAAA",\n           "handle": "subscription-101",\n           "create_customer": {\n              "handle": "customer-007",\n              "email": "joe@example.com"\n           },\n           "signup_method":"link"}');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```